# How to Copy a Woocommerce Product's Variations From One Product to Another

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product-variations

I am trying to copy a products variations using PHP from one existing product to another.
This way I can copy the variations without duplicating the exact product and having to re input the other non variation customization for that product. I don't know why there isn't  a simple plugin for this.

Here is what I have so far, I just don't know how to copy into the new product given both products id's.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        
        if ($_POST['product_type'] == 'panoramic') {
        $product = wc_get_product( 54721 );

        }
        if ($_POST['product_type'] == 'wide-panoramic') {

                            $product = wc_get_product( 54730 );

        }
        $variations = $product->get_available_variations();
        $new_product = wc_get_product($_POST['product_id_to_fill']);
        $new_product->set_available_variations($variations);
}
```

(set_available_variations is not actually a function) which is why I've hit a wall.

Comment: Why duplicate a product and re individualize the product when it is already set up with everything but the new variations.  This is why I am looking for a programming way to only copy in new variations to an existing product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a straightforward function like `set_available_variations` to transfer the variation, have to write a custom code for it, here is the code that I used in one of my own wordpress project, you can modify as per your requirement

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    
    $source_product_id = 54721; 
    $target_product_id = $_POST['product_id_to_fill']; // The ID of the product you want to copy variations to

    $source_product = wc_get_product($source_product_id);

    // Check if the source product has variations
    if ($source_product->is_type('variable')) {
        // Get the variations of the source product
        $variations = $source_product->get_children();

        foreach ($variations as $variation_id) {
            $variation = wc_get_product($variation_id);

            // Create a new variation for the target product
            $new_variation = new WC_Product_Variation();
            $new_variation->set_parent_id($target_product_id);

            // Set attributes and other settings from the source variation
            $new_variation->set_attributes($variation->get_attributes());
            $new_variation->set_regular_price($variation->get_regular_price());
            $new_variation->set_sale_price($variation->get_sale_price());
            $new_variation->set_stock_quantity($variation->get_stock_quantity());
            $new_variation->set_weight($variation->get_weight());

            // Save the new variation
            $new_variation->save();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! So this works great, I am just hoping to delete all the old variations in the target product before adding the new. Is there an easy way to do that?

Comment: To delete all the old variations of the target product before adding new ones, you can use the wc_delete_product function provided by WooCommerce. This function takes the ID of a product or variation and deletes it.

Comment: I couldn't find wc_delete_product but wp_delete_ post worked
I added this before copying the variations with your code.

                $taget_variations = $target_product->get_children();
                foreach ($taget_variations as $variation_id) {
                    wp_delete_post( $variation_id );
                }

Comment: Thanks a lot, before I saw your answer this morning I was going to plunge into duplicating the product and saving all the other settings of the old product in variables and importing them to the new.  I may just make my first simple plugin with your solution.